# Menu Items not getting displayed when making nav visible through css media queries

Tags: css, class-visibility

I am having horizontal menu bar which I don't want to display for screens having width < 610 px. For that I am setting my nav tag as :

```
nav{display:none;}
```

Now, I am writing my media query as :

```
@media screen and (min-width:610px){nav{display:block;}}
```

When I am checking for screen size>610px , I am getting only blank menu bar without any menu list item.By the way, I am also using z-index:2 for my `<ul>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following, note the changes I made.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bxcZT/)

```
@media screen and (max-width:610px){
    nav{
        display:none;
    }
}
```